# How to fit background image in all screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass, background-image

i am having issues with my background image. Somehow on big screen the head is cut off to fit the screen. Is there a way to ensure that 100% of the picture is always rendered regardless of size of the screen?
initial property of background-size is cover but when set this way the top of the image is cut to fit the container. When i change background-size to 100% 100% as per below i get the result i want but the quality of the image is impacted. Is there a way to work around this. I have reviews most documentation related to background-image but none of them give me the result i want.
both html and body  height/width are set to 100%.

Thanks in advance for the help.
Leo

```
.main .masthead {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 7.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 7.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8)), to(rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8))), url(/_next/static/media/dr.cut_thebarbershow_blue.4a28589b.jpg);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8) 0%, rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8) 100%), url(/_next/static/media/dr.cut_thebarbershow_blue.4a28589b.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

[sandbox](https://kids8.sse.codesandbox.io/)

Comment: I guess your best option would be to leave it with `background-size: cover;` and change the position according to the image, `background-position: center top`.

Comment: From the MDN site: *Cover scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.* I'd say the best option is leaving it as `cover` and changing the `background-position` else, using a different image for mobile devices.

Comment: thanks @MattHamer5 for your time. it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You should use cover or auto in media query so it will cover the whole area as per screen size.

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: thanks so much for your time, i have tried what you have recommended but it does not work like expected, i have added a link to a sandbox so you can see the issue on big screen. https://kids8.sse.codesandbox.io/  Thanks again

Comment: this one doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

To fit the background image to fit the screen size we could set the background-size property to contain. On setting the background-size to contain; it tells the browser that the image scales to fit the content area without losing its aspect ratio

For more understanding refer the link provided:
https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/responsive-image#setting-background-size-to-fit-screen

Comment: Hi @pooja thanks for your time as explain to  Sanjay i have tried all what you guys have recommended but it doesn't work. I have set a sandbox to show the issue maybe it can give you a better idea of the issue. Thanks again https://kids8.sse.codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 1):

It is best to have the following settings in your main CSS file to delete all surrounding spaces by default

```css
body,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Then consider the following styles for the body:

```css
body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8)), to(rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8))),
    url(/_next/static/media/dr.cut_thebarbershow_blue.4a28589b.jpg);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8) 0%, rgba(92, 77, 66, 0.8) 100%),
    url(/_next/static/media/dr.cut_thebarbershow_blue.4a28589b.jpg);
}
```

If your image deteriorates, download your image and use Photoshop or other tools to maintain image quality.